# Automate logging into raspberry pi (connected using wifi router) and run commands

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I am a Mac user and I want to automate the process of entering the password to ssh into Raspberry pi, run a few commands and transfer files to my local computer. I am new to bash scripting and was wondering what the general structure of my code should look like. I connect to the pi using a wifi router, so when I open the terminal, it automatically asks me for the password.

EDIT: I was able to use sshpass in my bash script but the following commands like top and kill don't execute. In fact, after I sshpass into my pi, it waits for me to enter a command in the terminal. Here is my shell script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'raspberry' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  pi@192.168.0.101
ssh -t pi@192.168.0.101 'sudo killall RPI_Log px4'
```

Comment: What happens if you run `ssh user@host echo hello`?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you write what command did you use.

Comment: So I basically log into the pi automatically. Then I have to type "exit", it relogs in but asks me to manually type password, prints hello and exits out of the pi.

Comment: After your sshpass command, can you check if `ssh -t pi@192.168.0.101 'echo <raspberry_password> | sudo -S killall RPI_Log px4'` gives you results?

Comment: sshpass is logging you in as you expect, but you're not passing the command you want executed, so it's leaving you logged into an interactive session (thus the need to _exit_.) The second line has the command you want, but isn't wrapped with sshpass. Try putting the remote command (_sudo ..._?) at the end of the sshpass line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you should be able to do something like:

```bash
# Run `command to run`
sshpass -pwhatever ssh user@host command to run

mkdir copied-documents
# Recursively copy `Documents` on `host` to `copied-documents` on this machine.
sshpass -pwhatever scp -r user@host:Documents copied-documents
```

A passwordless keypair is probably safer than a password in a script, though, even though it's not the height of security. After you create a keypair and set it up on your machine and the Raspberry Pi, you can probably also edit `~/.ssh/config` on your Mac to something like:

```
Host *
  Compression yes
  CompressionLevel 9
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/.socket-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 60
  ServerAliveInterval 15

Host pi
  HostName 192.168.0.101
  User pi
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now you can use `ssh pi command to run` and `scp -r pi:Documents copied-documents`. Note that `sshpass` is no longer needed and `pi` is easier to type than `pi@192.168.0.101`. Plus, you only need to update `~/.ssh/config` if the username or host changes (or you want to add another user@host combination).

Comment: So I am assuming scp copies the files I need but can I also use kill command in a similar manner?

Comment: @YuktiKathuria Yes, to `kill` on the remote host, `ssh pi@192.168.0.101 kill whatever`. To stop `scp`, just press Ctrl+C.